# Backslashes added to the arraylist elements when a request is sent

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm converting JSONObjects to string, storing them in an arraylist, and sending them in a POST request as a field parameter like so:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/cat/{id}/name")
Cat postCat(@Path("id") String catId, @Field("cat") ArrayList<CatModel> cat);
```

But when I see the network logs on the server side, I see that backslahes are added to the request I send:

```
{"cat":["{\"time\":\"2017-08-31 07:16:00\",\"name\":\"0\",\"age\":\"0\"}, "id":"123"]
```

What's the reason for this, and how do I eliminate them?

I'm using retrofit 1.9

Comment: Request is failing?

Comment: No, request is going through.

Comment: Then something is wrong received on server side?